# Не работает модуль shutil

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, python-3.6, shutil

Вот код

```
import shutil
shutil.copy('C:\56\doc0.txt','C:\45')
```

но после выполнения программы `doc.txt` остаётся в той же папке и меняется на файл с именем `%`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём проблема?

Comment: Как минимум точно два слэша \\ вместо одного надо ставить

Comment: спасибо добрый человек теперь всё работает)))))

Answer (score 6):

Вместо

```
shutil.copy('C:\56\doc0.txt','C:\45')
```

используйте

```
shutil.copy(r'C:\56\doc0.txt', r'C:\45')
```

(`r` перед строкой в апострофах или кавычкая значит *raw* - сырой, т. е. знаки принимаются *буквенно* - не интерпретируются).

---

**Объяснение:**

В строке

```
'C:\56\doc0.txt','C:\45'
```

последовательности знаков `\56` и`\45` *интерпретируются* как знаки `.` и `%`.

Вы можете проверить это в консоли Питона. Напишите:

```
print('C:\56\doc0.txt','C:\45')
```

и на выводе вы получите

> ```
> C:.\doc0.txt C:%
> ```

Это происходит *в соответствии с документацией* (см. таблицы в [2.4.1. String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) или [Escape Characters](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/escapes.html)) для которой они соответствуют символом с *восьмеричными значениями* `56` и `45`, т. е. `.` и `%` (сp. с [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/)).

Answer (score 1):

В [соседнем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/847635/201445) вам уже объяснили хитрость слешей `\`.

Но вы можете использовать слеш `/`, тогда не придется экранировать или использовать "сырые строки":

```
import shutil
shutil.copy('C:/56/doc0.txt', 'C:/45')
```